# JDK Configuration Missingon on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've reinstall both Intellij & JDK 18, double checked Project structure where JDK does set up. But "Run" button is still disappear and I am required to Edit Configuration. It works perfectly fine yesterday and all the sudden the Run Button not working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUyPv.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DVb4.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbNsE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your Java class is located outside of the [Sources Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories). Drag&Drop the class under `src` directory, open the class in the editor and click on green run arrow to launch the program.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html to get more familiar with Java development process in IntelliJ IDEA.